# Store Binary Items in Spring Embedded LDAP

Tags: java, spring, binary, ldap

I hope somebody of you can help me with a problem with the Spring Embedded LDAP.
I use the embedded LDAP for mocking the productive Active Directory in Unit tests but there is a problem.

The LDAP is set up correctly (it boots) and is prefilled with a `schema.ldif`.

And here comes the Problem:

In the Active Directory is a binary attribute at the user which will be read as `byte[]` in the user representing class via `LdapTemplate`. In Active Directory everything works fine. But in the Spring embedded LDAP the field is always a String and than I get an `ConversionException` when i try to read it.

Is there any way to tell Spring in the LDIF (or somewhere else) that this attribute is a binary attribute so that the value is stored as an byte[] or the string is returned as byte[] ?

I tried to add it as Base64 Encoded String with the `::` notation and also as file with the `:<` notation. but both ways store it as String in the LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the question by my own. If someone has the same Issue again here is my solution:

The issue is not that the attribute is stored as String, it is the client environment which is configured wrong when using the embedded LDAP.

In the client you set the environment property via `application.properties` like this:
`spring.ldap.base-environment.java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary=propertyName`.

When the `ContextSource` of the ldap client is initialised this property will be put in the context and the attribute will be resolved as binary.

But the `ContextSource` of the client is annotated with `ConditionalOnMissingBean`. So if a bean of `ContextSource` already existis the bean will not be initialised again.

If you are using an embedded LDAP it creates its own `ContextSource` before the client so the client uses the same ContextSource as the Server. In this `ContextSource` the `binary` property is not present.

Thats the reason of my issue, the property is not set.

There is no way to set the property as Environment Property via application.properties.

My solution is an `ApplicationListener` which sets the property to the source after initialisation.

```java
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * This optimizer is necessary because the property cannot be set otherwise.
 * The LDAP Client initialises it`s ContextSource (with the property from the application.properties) on ConditionalOnMissingBean.
 * By using the embedded LDAP the bean is no longer missing and the ContextSource from the embedded LDAP is used.
 * This bean does not use any properties for the environment.
 * So we are using this optimizer to set the properties afterwards.
 */
@Component
public class LdapContextSourceOptimizer implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        AbstractContextSource contextSource = contextRefreshedEvent.getApplicationContext().getBean(AbstractContextSource.class);
        contextSource.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(Collections.singletonMap("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectGUID"));
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been looking for the reference doc mentioning the spring.ldap.base-environment.java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary property ? Where did  you find it?